# React POST request return error 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: javascript, post, react-redux, fetch-api

I created an API with my Rails data. I would like to add data from React and for that I use a POST request:

```
export async function createUserCours(user_cours) {
  console.log(user_cours);
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user_cours)
  };

  const response = await fetch('/api/v1/cours_users', options);
  console.log(response);
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    type: 'USER_COURS_CREATED',
    payload: data
  }
}
```

But the fetch request fail and return an 422 status error (Unprocessable Entity).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the solution : isable CSRF protection. You can edit your Controller with this:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```